# Is it possible to make a parameterized scripted pipeline in Jenkins by listing the parameters in actual script, not in job config

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#pipeline-syntax-overview), I can specify the parameter that the pipeline expects right in the pipeline script like so:

```
pipeline {
   parameters([
    string(name: 'DEPLOY_ENV', defaultValue: 'TESTING' )
   ])
}
```

is it possible do to in a scripted pipline? I know I can do this :

[image]

BUT, IS IT POSSIBLE TO DO THIS:

```
node{
   parameters([
    string(name: 'DEPLOY_ENV', defaultValue: 'TESTING' )
   ])
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I found a solution by experimentation so want to share it:

```
properties(
    [
        parameters([
                string(defaultValue: '/data', name: 'Directory'),
                string(defaultValue: 'Dev', name: 'DEPLOY_ENV')
        ])   
    ]
)  

node {
// params.DEPLOY_ENV ...
}
```

Comment: Also, the `properties ( ... )`  section doesn't need to be part of a node { ... } declaration

Comment: This doesn't work for me! When I pass the parameter it basically ignores it. I'm trying to access the parameter like `env.DEPLOY_ENV`

Comment: env.xxx is an environment variable, @xbmono , need to think of shell variables differently to job-parameters

Comment: Note that boolean params use `booleanParam(...)`, and credentials use `credentials(...)`.  I believe choice uses `choice(...)` - this is untested.  Also note that the first run of the job does not prompt for parameters, but does create them in the job.

Answer (score 13):

I highly recommend using the "Snippet Generator" for first time use of figuring this out. It will allow you to use a GUI that looks maybe exactly like the snapshot you shared above, to fill out the settings you want, and generate the appropriate syntax.  For this question in-particular, select the sample step "properties: Set job properties" from the Snippet Generator

You can access the "Snippet Generator" from any Jenkins server by going to the `/pipeline-syntax` endpoint.

For more info on the snippet generator see: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator

Answer (score 3):

I did create it outside and it worked! Also, I'm using the boolean value and it's working like a charm on a `scripted` version

```
// Parameters for the build
properties([
  parameters([
     booleanParam(name: 'DEPLOY_SHA', defaultValue: false),
  ])
])

podTemplate(name: ptNameVersion, label: ptNameVersion, containers: [
...
...
]
```

It shows the parameter

[image: Screen Shot 2019-03-29 at 4 37 29 PM]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jenkins job DSL plugin for generating jobs, pipelines, multi-branch pipelines... The DSL allows the definition of a job, and then offers a useful set of functions to configure common Jenkins items. A configure is available to give direct access to the config.xml before generating the job.  With parameters block you can then easily define any type of parameters with their default values and description. Note that this plugin is also compatible with git and other version control systems.

```
jobDsl scriptText: ''' job('example') {
    parameters {
        stringParam('Parameter Name', 'Default Value' , 'Parameter Description')
    }
    scm {
        perforceP4('p4_credentials') {
            workspace {
                manual('ws_name', '//depot/Tools/build/... //ws_name/build/...')
            }
        configure { node ->
                    node / workspace / spec / clobber('true')
            }
        }
    }
}'''
```

References:

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-scm-perforceP4

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin