# How to pass paramaters to bash script in a Jenkins scripted pipeline and set the credentials to remote host login

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins scripted pipeline. Below is the code which i'm trying to execute on a remote host. I want to know, two things:

1) How to pass credentials without hard coding it. Unlike the way i did in the script below.

2) How can i pass a parameter to my test.sh script. Meaning I want to pass it as

```
sshScript remote: remote, script: "myscript.sh {version} "
```

**Update:**

Below, is the script I got:

```
node {
        properties([
        parameters([
            string(name: 'version', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter the version in x.y.z format')
        ])
    ]) 
         version = params.version.trim()
         def remote = [:]
         remote.name = 'Filetransfer'
         remote.host = 'X.X.XX.XXXX'
         remote.allowAnyHosts = true

     withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'saltmaster', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'ops')]) {
        remote.user = ops
        remote.password = password    
            stage('Filetransfer') {
                  sshCommand remote: remote, command: "hostname" 
                //sshCommand remote: remote, command: "whoami"
                  sshGet remote: remote, from: '/srv/salt/tm-server/files/docker-compose.yaml', into: '/home/jenkins/jenkins-data/docker-compose.yaml', override: true
                 //sshScript remote: remote, script: '/home/jenkins/jenkins-data/rebuilt_dockercompose.sh "${version}"'

            }

                sh 'echo "Executing the script now ..."'
                sh "echo Current version: ${version}"
                sh "/home/jenkins/jenkins-data/rebuilt_dockercompose.sh //"${version}//""   

    }
}
```

Comment: For (1), you can add the credentials to Jenkins credential store and use the `withCredentials` directive in your pipeline (See https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin/blob/master/README.adoc#withcredentials). This will also mask in credentials if you happen to print them in the log. For (2), you should be able to pass the argument with a Dollar symbol `sshScript remote: remote, script: "myscript.sh ${version}"`.

Comment: Thanks. But, Where and how to create the version parameter? I want it to be passed by the user each time they want to run it.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: Great. For some reason Jenkins is not able to understand the value 6.6.6.6 is the command line argument. I'm getting the below error: parameterjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/myscript.sh 6.6.6.6. does not exist. here 6.6.6. is passed by the user. Inside the script i take the value as $1 parameter.

Comment: Is `6.6.6.6` the version string? Try escaping it once or twice as needed `script: "myscript.sh \\"${version}\\""`.

Comment: yes. i tried as: sshScript remote: remote, script: "my_script.sh \"${version}\" as well as sshScript remote: remote, script: "myscript.sh \\"${version}\\" . Unfortunatley, when i hit apply it says "execting anything , but got "\n". No luck.

Comment: Ok, looks like a trailing newline character is being introduced. See if the script runs in Jenkins if you pass `6.6.6.6` directly as an argument. If yes, add this inside your stage before calling the script - `version = params.version.trim()` or `env.version = params.version.trim()` to remove leading and trailing whitespaces and newlines from the parameter.

Comment: Let me know what worked.

Comment: @DibakarAditya, Thanks for all the input. Initially, when I was running the script inside a docker based Jenkins environment the Jenkins was working wired. Upon use of trim option the problem is resolved. I have updated the code above for others reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

**Pass credentials without hard-coding**

1. In your Jenkins instance, [add a global credential](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/#adding-new-global-credentials) of type **SSH Username with private key**.
2. In your pipeline, use the `withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey...])` directive from [Credential Binding Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) to pass the credentials. This will also mask the credentials in the console output.

**Pass user defined parameters**

1. Since yours is a scripted pipeline, use the `parameters([string...])` block wrapped inside the `properties([])` block to allow users enter the version as a [string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747772/is-it-possible-to-make-a-parameterized-scripted-pipeline-in-jenkins-by-listing-t).
2. Pass the parameter as an argument to your shell script.

**Modified pipeline script**

```
node {
    properties([
        parameters([
            string(name: 'version', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter the version in x.y.z format')
        ])
    ]) 
    def remote = [:]
    remote.name = 'testPlugin'
    remote.host = 'x.x.x.x'
    remote.allowAnyHosts = true

    withCredentials([
        sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'ssh-credentials', usernameVariable: 'ssh-user', passphraseVariable: 'ssh-pass')
    ]) {
        remote.user = ssh-user
        remote.password = ssh-pass

        stage('testPlugin') {
            sshPut remote: remote, from: 'myscript.sh', into: '.'
            sshScript remote: remote, script: "myscript.sh ${version}"               
        }
    }
}
```