# How to implement build after another project is built through a Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

For a project A I want to trigger it's build when B is built successfully.I can achieve this through the Jenkins console by selecting the option from Build trigger.

Now I wanna achieve this by writing corresponding steps in Jenkins file of project A.

What steps can be used
I tried
triggers{ upstream('B',hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
}

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers :

The upstream trigger "accepts a comma-separated string of jobs and a threshold. When any job in the string finishes with the minimum threshold, the Pipeline will be re-triggered. For example: `triggers { upstream(upstreamProjects: 'job1,job2', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS) }`"

To trigger a build of Project A after Project B has been built successfully, Project A's JenkinsFile might look like:

```
properties(
  [pipelineTriggers(
    [upstream(
        upstreamProjects: 'project_b_job_path',
        threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS         
    )]
  )]
)
```

where `project_b_job_path` is equal to the **absolute** or **relative** path of the job, for example:

- `projects/project_b/master`
- `../project_b/master`
- `test_branch`

Comment: Hey so I did tried this but properties is not recognized in the version I am using
So just triggers{ ...} as mentioned in the pipeline should work right
Also the properties step can be added inside pipeline as an independent function right  pipeline{ agent {} properties (...)} ?

Comment: @PranavPawar, why don't you test out just using `triggers{...}` and let us know? The properties step is an independent function that can be declared inside or outside of the pipeline as long as it's declared **before** the stages that use its contents (according to this answer and comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53750165/5568675). What version of Jenkins are you using that doesn't have `properties[(...)]`?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you can also make the change for this only in project B. Add a step in the post actions of project B to build project A when B is successful:

**PROJECT B:**

```
pipeline{
    agent{
        label "node"
    }
    stages{
        stage("A"){
            steps{
                echo "========executing A========"
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        success{
            build propagate: false, job: 'A'
        }
    }
}
```

`post {}` will be execute when project B is built and the code inside `success {}` will only be executed when project B is successful.
`build propagate: false, job: 'A'` will call project A. `propogate: false` ensures that project B does not wait for project A's completion and simply invokes it.

Comment: The explaination is incorrect.

`propagate` is used to propagate errors from the downstream job.
`wait` actually determines if the upstream project waits or not.

If you dont want to wait, use something like  `build job: 'A', propagate: false, wait: false`.

Refer: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/